# Whitespace viewport dependency (should CTAs be visible or not)

Tags: white-space, cta, viewport

[image: 1680x1050 viewport_2]
[image: 1680x1050 viewport_1]

We've read few Q&A on this topic, also done the research but most of the articles says what whitespace is, not how to calculate it.

**When designing for smaller screens, should the whitespace shrink accordingly so all the CTAs stay always visible in the viewport or should there be an element which gives the user purpose for scrolling and then finding the CTA?**

Checked few whitespace examples, like:

Apple, 
Emark.com, 
Kissmetrics.com/product, 
Amazon.com
Etsy.com

and they all seem to not care about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace places elements and text that are pleasing to the eye and help create a look and feel for the application or website that is trying to convey a message to the user about how the owner wants to be perceived.

That aside, the purpose of an application or site is to provide some functionality, therefore the answer is to balance the design with the usability of your site.

Once elements are being forced off screen because you're maintaining a rigid layout, it's time to look at the layout.

Comment: Thank You Daryll. So in conclusion, Your advice would be to shrink the elements and show the CTA on the same viewport. We also stand for usability over design but were curious if there are any researches on that particular topic.

Comment: I'm sure there is, my comment is from experience!